# Error handling in Node.js at all times

Tags: node.js, error-handling

I want to run some important code before node.js exits with whatever exit code, or is restarted with any daemon (eg: pm2, forever) at all times. The code is not synchronous however, so here is the question. Is a handler like the below sufficient?

```
process.stdin.resume();

//Won't use because it can only run synchronous code.
process.on("exit", code => console.log("Process has exited with code "+code));
process.on("SIGINT", err => exit_handler(err, "SIGINT"));
process.on("SIGUSR1", err => exit_handler(err, "SIGUSR1"));
process.on("SIGUSR2", err => exit_handler(err, "SIGUSR2"));
process.on("unhandledRejection", err => exit_handler(err, "unhandledRejection"));

function exit_handler(err, type)
{
    //handle error, run code.
    if (err) console.error(err.stack);
    process.exit();
}
```

The [events](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_signal_events) in question.

Answer (score 0):

I'd also suggest adding:

```
process.on('uncaughtException', err => exit_handler(err, "uncaughtException"));
```

I'd be worried about relying completely on these handlers, however, I'd suggest using something like Forever: https://github.com/foreverjs/forever to monitor the script. I'm not sure if you can get Forever to run a script on exit, however it will restart your script if it exits which might be an opportunity to do anything you need at this point. There is also Upstart and Monit which do something similar.

It's nice to put together a test script to exercise all this as well, e.g.

```
"Use strict";

var fs = require('fs');

process.stdin.resume();

var promise1 = new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(resolve, 30000);
});

//Won't use because it can only run synchronous code.
process.on("exit", code => console.log("Process has exited with code "+code));
process.on("SIGINT", err => exit_handler(err, "SIGINT"));
process.on("SIGUSR1", err => exit_handler(err, "SIGUSR1"));
process.on("SIGUSR2", err => exit_handler(err, "SIGUSR2"));
process.on("unhandledRejection", err => exit_handler(err, "unhandledRejection"));
process.on('uncaughtException', err => exit_handler(err, "uncaughtException"));

function exit_handler(err, type)
{
    //handle error, run code.
    if (err) console.error("exit_handler: " + err.stack);
    process.exit();
}

function testError()
{

    fs.readFile('some file that doesnt exist.txt', function (err, data) {
        if (err) throw err;
    });
}

// Deliberately cause an error.
setTimeout (testError, 1000);


console.log('Waiting..');
promise1.then(() => {
    console.log('Exiting');
});
```